# UITextView displaying spaces after newline/wordwrap

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uitextview

I am using a UITextView to display arbitrary NSStrings, with various font sizes (depending on the length of the string, and the screen resolution of the device).  My problem is that the UITextView seems to display these little "underscore like" characters, instead of spaces, if the space character is the first character on a newline (after the text has been wrapped).  Anyone know a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think this was a problem with the font I was using.  Also possibly the text size of the font was important.  Perhaps the fact that I was displaying in italic was the thing.  Anyhow, now that I have a different font, different size, not italic, I haven't noticed this problem.